# Disable a form's KeyDown after timer.stop()

Tags: c#, timer, windows-forms-designer, keydown

I just created a letter game. While the timer is on it prints letters to a listbox.
The user must press the correct key. If he does, a label with the mumber of correct presses is updated. If not, a missed label is updated. In both cases, the Total and and accuracy label is updated. 
The problem is that after the game is over it still counts.
The thing I want to do is disable keyDown event from happening on the form.
I wrote this code but doesn't work.

```
timer1.Stop();
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.KeyPreview = false;
```

Does anyone has a solution?

This is my code. Even if I add a flag, the form, even after the game is over, has keyDown Event enabled. I want to know if there is a way to **disable the keyDown event from happening** after the game finishes.

namespace TypingGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Stats stats = new Stats();

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Here the game starts
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add((Keys) random.Next(65,90));
        //If letters missed are more than 7 the game is over
        //so I need a way to disable the KeyDown event from happening after the game is over
        if (listBox1.Items.Count > 7)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Game Over");
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
    //Here is what happens on KeyDown.
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(e.KeyCode);
            listBox1.Refresh();
            if (timer1.Interval > 400)
            {
                timer1.Interval -= 10;
            }
            if (timer1.Interval > 250)
            {
                timer1.Interval -= 7;
            }
            if (timer1.Interval > 100)
            {
                timer1.Interval -= 2;
            }
            difficultyProgressBar.Value = 800 - timer1.Interval;

            stats.Update(true);
        }
        else
        {
            stats.Update(false);
        }

        correctLabel.Text = "Correct: " + stats.Correct;
        missedLabel.Text = "Missed: " + stats.Missed;
        totalLabel.Text = "Total: " + stats.Total;
        accuracyLabel.Text = "Accuracy" + stats.Accuracy + "%";

    }
}
```

}

Comment: how about put a flag to indicate the game is over

Comment: What you mean put a flag? The game works fine and prints Game Over to a label. I want after the flag and the end of the game, the user to not be able to trigger a KeyDown event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code base on your code.

[MSDN Reference - Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
//Here the game starts (?? game stop?)
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add((Keys) random.Next(65,90));
    //If letters missed are more than 7 the game is over
    //so I need a way to disable the KeyDown event from happening after the game is over
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 7)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Game Over");
        // timer1.Stop(); 
        // disable the timer to stop
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
//Here is what happens on KeyDown.
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // if timer disabled, do nothing
    if (!timer1.Enabled) return;

    if (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.KeyCode))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(e.KeyCode);
        listBox1.Refresh();
        if (timer1.Interval > 400)
        {
            timer1.Interval -= 10;
        }
        if (timer1.Interval > 250)
        {
            timer1.Interval -= 7;
        }
        if (timer1.Interval > 100)
        {
            timer1.Interval -= 2;
        }
        difficultyProgressBar.Value = 800 - timer1.Interval;

        stats.Update(true);
    }
    else
    {
        stats.Update(false);
    }

    correctLabel.Text = "Correct: " + stats.Correct;
    missedLabel.Text = "Missed: " + stats.Missed;
    totalLabel.Text = "Total: " + stats.Total;
    accuracyLabel.Text = "Accuracy" + stats.Accuracy + "%";

}
```

Comment: Alex thanks a lot for your help. I added the code above.